# Method that takes a Point object as a parameter and returns true or false depending on whether this is within the straight section or not

Tags: java

I have an exercise about classes: One method says that: Takes a Point object as a parameter and returns true or false depending on whether this is within the straight section or not. A simple way to find out whether a point A is within the straight section defined by the points B, C is to check that the length of BC is equal to the sum of the lengths of BA, AC.

To avoid inaccuracies due to the representation of double numbers instead of exact equality between two quantities we check if the absolute value of their difference is quite "small".
For this method, check that the absolute value of the difference is less than 0.01 (so quantities are considered equal).

I understand that when we want to compare two quantities a, b and there is a problem of accuracy, then instead of checking if a == b we check if | a-b | <= a small number

| A-b | is the absolute value of their difference. For example, if BC is 19.456, BA + AC is 19.457 then we calculate | 19.456-19.457 | which is 0.001. If this difference is small enough to be considered negligible, then we say that the quantities are "equal".

How can I implement that?

Comment: Your question is too broad. First of all, I do not see a question there. Why you cannot implement it in your code? Do you know how to define method? Do you know how to add parameters to method?

Comment: Yes i know my first try is these  public double contains(Point p){
        double A;
        double B;
        double initp;
        double  i = B + A;
        double i1 = B + initp;
        double i2 = A + initp;

Answer (score 1):

Here is a java class that solves it :)

```
public class Point {

  public static final double DISTANCE_TOLERANCE = 0.1;

  private final double x;
  public double getX() { return this.x; }

  private final double y;
  public double getY() {return this.y; }

  public Point(final double x, final double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }

  public double getDistanceWithOtherPoint(final Point other) {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.getX() - other.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(this.getY() - other.getY(), 2));
  }

  public boolean isPointInTheSameLineAs(final Point b, final Point c) {
    final double distanceFromThisToB = this.getDistanceWithOtherPoint(b);
    final double distanceFromThisToC = this.getDistanceWithOtherPoint(c);
    final double distanceBetweenBandC = b.getDistanceWithOtherPoint(c);
    return Math.abs( (distanceFromThisToB + distanceFromThisToC) - distanceBetweenBandC) <= DISTANCE_TOLERANCE;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point A = new Point(5.1,3.2);
    Point B = new Point(7.5,2.7);
    Point C = new Point(9.3,4.8);

    System.out.println("Is Point A in the same line segment as B and C? " + A.isPointInTheSameLineAs(B, C));
  }
}
```